# Ctrl + A in skin modifier with proportional editing

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]

Hey I need help, I don't want to make this super long and I'll go straight to the point.

I want to make the ends of the tree thin using sharp proportional editing, but when I ctrl + a (with proportional editing enabled) it affects everything, as if I selected everything to scale. I used old version of blender and it has no problem like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you simply have your circle of proportional editing too big, after pressing Ctrl A scroll the mouse wheel and check in the top left corner the proportional size, and reduce it until it's right.

You can also manually enter the radius values of the branches.

Try also changing your transform pivot point from "individual origins" to "median point".

Nothing changed from previous versions in this area.

[image]

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e5b894948306e038b46af1bf2e0e9d10

Take a look at this link, I used CTRL + A with proportional editing, it affects all.

Radius X and Y is useless because I cannot use proportional editing there and CTRL - A is more convinient and faster.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: It works now thank yoou, I should change it to "Median Points" instead of "Individual Origins".